# Persist React Cookie-based Authentication state

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-router, jwt, session-cookies

I'm building an authentication flow using React-Router & Redux where my backend returns a JWT in the form of a Session Cookie (with a Set-Cookie HTTP header) which the Frontend uses in order to make subsequent requests. (I'm not using localStorage as the general recommendation is to prefer a Cookie because of the risk of it being readable by JS in case of XSS)

```html
// my App component
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

          <Container>
            {!isAuthenticated ? (
              <LoginForm />
            ) : (
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={MessageList} />
                <Route path="/messages" component={MessageList} />
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
                <Route path="/message/:id" component={MessageContainer} />
              </Switch>
            )}
          </Container>
```

```js
// the api requests themselves abstracted
const login = (data) =>
  axios
    .post("auth/login", data, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => response.data);

const fetchItems = (page, token) =>
  axios(`message/list/page/${page}`, {
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then((response) => response.data);
```

```js
// actions
function handleError(err) {
  return {
    type: "ERROR_OCCURED",
    payload: err,
  };
}

function shouldFetchMessages(state, page) {
  if (!state.message.all.length) {
    return true;
  } else if (state.message.isFetching) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return state.message.all;
  }
}

export let getMessages = (page = 1) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  let err, response;

  dispatch(requestMessages(page));
  [err, response] = await to(api.fetchItems(page, getState().user.accessToken));
  if (err) {
    return handleError(err);
  }
  return dispatch(receiveMessages(response));
};

export function getMessagesIfNeeded(page) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchMessages(getState(), page)) {
      return dispatch(getMessages(page));
    }
  };
}
```

```js
// reducer
// where would the localStorage isAuthenticated value be synced with the store?
export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // skipped the other reducers for brevity
    case "ERROR_OCCURED":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false, // this should be saved in the localStorage
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I need to have a `BOOLEAN` which holds the 'state' of `isAuthenticated` so I can show the appropriate component.

My main problem is that Redux state is of course not persisting across page refreshes.

I thought of having a `localStorage` variable, (or a new `cookie`). (The Cookie that contains the JWT is `httpOnly` and from my understanding cannot be accessed by JavaScript).

Questions:

- is this an established practice
- how would be JWT expiration be handled? (I guess I could set it to false if the HTTP request would fail with 401.)
- where would the localStorage variable be synchronized with the Redux state to avoid side-effects in my Reducers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not an expert in this area, but in my app, whenever I set or remove the httpOnly JWT cookie, I also set/remove a regular cookie with info on whether the user is logged in, and their role. Then you have something you can check on the client side without exposing anything sensitive.

Comment: My answer wasn't very concise. Set isAuthenticated as a non-HTTP-only cookie that expires at the same time as the HTTP-only sensitive cookie. 

Whenever the user makes an action that accesses the API, their auth will be checked, and you can refresh their session time if you like.